# VB 6 app,Failling to create run time object of printlibrary.print of FILENET in Windows 7

Tags: vb6, filenet

I am in desperate need of a fix. I have an app developed in VB6. It uses the IBM Filenet.
Now the app uses the filenet viewer and then the printer to print some docs. The printe

object is created at run time.

```
Set obg=CreateObject("PrintLibrary.Print")
```

This app is running smooth in Windows Xp for both Admin and non Admin users.But when this app is run from Windows 7 environment, only the user having admin privileges can run it and others can not. When others try to run this app, it throws an error from the above mentioned line of code. The error code is

```
run time error 2147220991 (80040201)
```

I guess, there is some permission issue with respect to a particular DLL but I am not successful in finding out which one.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In windows explorer, go to the path were your application executable is available. Right click on the application icon and select "run as administrator". Check whether you get the problem now also.

Comment: Thanks Rags, but will the user have to select "Run as Administrator" every time they want to run the app?

Comment: Check : 1. http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/ and 2. http://superuser.com/questions/614709/run-a-program-as-admin-all-the-time

Comment: Just to answer your first question Rags, it didn't work. Any other way? Running it as admin didn't work.

Comment: I guess , now we have to think of the root cause of this problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

The code for PrintLibrary.dll need to be changed to look for the filenet printers at hkey local machine\software\wow6432node\filenet print\configuration for windows 7.